# What arithmetic would you do in parallel?

Tags: nt.number-theory, big-list, computer-science, enumerative-combinatorics

This is a post asking for references, and soliciting problems and people interested in accelerated computing.  I will add the big-list tag and make it community-wiki.  If this interests you strongly, jump to the bottom for time-sensitive information.

I am looking for references on porting mathematical code to parallel-processing clusters.  To limit the field, I am interested in implementing algorithms that do mainly integer arithmetic. Number theoretic functions, enumeration problems, integer invariants of structures, and so on. Ideally these are tested algorithms that are amenable to a simple rewrite using techniques from parallel programming, with a twist that GPUs will be used.  (A lot of code using floating point already exists, mainly in the form of linear algebra libraries and the like. I am not so interested in those, but a well written paper that talks about implementation issues may be of interest.). So the first request is for papers by people who understand the mathematics and the computational issues involved in such ports explaining these issues to me, especially regarding multiprecision integer arithmetic done in parallel.

The second request is for open source software to port, or a description of an algorithm that is easy to implement and mathematically interesting to some research professionals (e.g. so that if I contribute to a research effort by this port, my name gets mentioned in a published journal) and is susceptible to substantial speed up on a parallel processing grid.  Preferably this is software in active use.

To forestall certain kinds of suggestions, I am not interested in working on cryptocurrency or bitcoin mining or decryption algorithms. I am also not interested in the Syracuse problem or in finding Mersenne primes unless it is clear how a grid can be used for something other than embarrassing parallelism (look it up) on these problems. You can add them to the list, but I have a more selective list of criteria that I will use to consider applications to port.

**Update 2019.05.16**: One of my deadlines has passed.  The paragraph below mostly holds, but you no longer need to be in the Bay Area to help out. I will divulge more in a future update, or to those who have an interest in helping now and contact me by email.  I am still looking for answers to the questions above.  **End Update 2019.05.16.**

I am putting together a team to attend a hackathon in the San Francisco Bay Area in mid July 2019.  If you are moderately interested but unlikely to attend, you can email me and I will send you some information about the event and how you might find a similar event near you. If you are strongly interested , have a good chance of being in the Bay Area at the right time, and want to learn more about parallel programming, email me now for details and a chance to join the team. (My deadline is in a few days.)  If you can't attend and don't want to learn but have a repo of code  to port that fits in with my agenda, make a post below.

Gerhard "Did I Mention Free Food?" Paseman, 2019.05.11.

Comment: Success story: Porting a conjecture of Erdos to SAT proved the conjecture. The unsat CNF formula was quite large, IIRC tens of gigabytes. Some SAT solvers are parallel out of the box.

Comment: @Joro, thanks! I may look at those codebases for ideas. Do you have any references where they talk about issues in porting these solvers to parallel systems?  Gerhard "Might Reinvent Wheel Many Times" Paseman, 2019.05.11.

Comment: I don't have reference. Consider checking the SAT competition http://www.satcompetition.org/

Comment: Are you asking only about parallel algorithms and tools or do you allow specific problems that have a chance of being solved by a "big box"?

Comment: For my immediate purpose I want code that works on small instances and has not yet been parallelized.  I could try to change existing parallel code to run on a different platform, but that is not optimal for me right now. For the question in general, I hope to see links to problems which could benefit from parallelization, but have not yet been done. Then when such a task has been done, we update the post to say so.  Gerhard "Big List With A Purpose" Paseman, 2019.05.12.

Comment: There are no good parallel implementations of graph isomorphism software.

Comment: @Brendan, if you wanted a good parallel implementation, would you start with the codebase from nauty? Or is there a different repository that would hold promise?  Gerhard "Wants Small Example To Start" Paseman, 2019.05.12.

Comment: Gerhard, All competive programs are based on partition refinement, so parallelising that might speed up all of them.  At a higher level, Traces is based on a BFS, which would be easier to parallelise than nauty's DFS, though it would not help in all circumstances.

Comment: @Brendan, I am about to consider (for the hackathon) parallelizing to GPU some of the code in Traces. Any other specific suggestions before I start? Also, what is wrong with other implementations that are advertised as parallel? Also, what is a main obstacle in having Traces do digraphs?  If the team succeeds, what would you like to do with the result?  Gerhard "Wanna Be A Team Member?" Paseman, 2019.05.14.

Comment: Please be specific about "other implementations".  As for digraphs in Traces, it is simply the case that the distributed version doesn't handle them.  They will be handled by a future version.  Lots of people use nauty/Traces/etc so a convincing parallelization would be of general purpose use.